# SpriteKit: How to simulate magnetic force

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am developing a game using iOS SpriteKit.  I am trying to make an object in this game that will pull things towards it and the force will get greater as objects come closer to it, think of a magnet or a black hole.  I've been having a difficult time figuring out what properties to change to get this nodes physicsBody to attract other nodes as they pass by.

Comment: Can't be done with simple properties. You'll have to calculate the distance between an object and an attractor and apply an impulse to the object towards the attractor based on its distance from the attractor and the attractor's presumable weight. If you want full-scale gravity simulation (every object is also an attractor) this can get very expensive since the number of calculations grows exponentially with the number of objects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In iOS 8 and OS X 10.10, SpriteKit has [`SKFieldNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html) for creating forces that apply to bodies in an area. This is great for things like buoyancy, area-specific gravity, and "magnets".

Watch out, though — the [`magneticField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/magneticField) you get from that class is probably not what you want for the kind of "magnets" gameplay you might be looking for. A magnetic field behaves as per [real-world physics at the micro level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force)... that is, it *deflects* moving, charged bodies. What we usually think of as magnets — the kind that stick to your fridge, pick up junked cars, or make a hoverboard fly — is [a higher-level effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetism) of that force.

If you want a field that just attracts anything (or some specific things) nearby, a `radialGravityField` is what you're really after. (To attract only specific things, use the `categoryBitMask` on the field and the `fieldBitMask` on the bodies it should/shouldn't interact with.)

If you want a field that attracts different things more or less strongly, or attracts some things and repels others, the `electricField` is a good choice. You can use the `charge` property of physics bodies to make them attracted or repelled (negative or positive values) or more or less strongly affected (greater or less absolute value) by the field.

---

Prior to iOS 8 & OS X 10.10, SpriteKit's physics simulation doesn't include such kinds of force.

That doesn't keep you from simulating it yourself, though. In your scene's `update:` method you can find the distances between bodies, calculate a force on each proportional to that distance (and to whatever strength of magnetic field you're simulating), and apply forces to each body.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Any examples out there that do just that?

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help, that should get me past this issue!

Answer (score 2):

yes you can create magnetic force in sprite kit

```c
-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
  [self updateCoin];
}

-(void) updateCoin
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"coin" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        CGPoint position;
        position=node.position;
        //move coin right to left
        position.x -= 10;
        node.position = position;
        //apply the magnetic force between hero and coin
        [self applyMagnetForce:coin];
        if (node.position.x <- 100)
            [node removeFromParent];

    }];
}

-(void)applyMagnetForce:(sprite*)node
{
    if( gameViewController.globalStoreClass.magnetStatus)
    {
        //if hero under area of magnetic force
        if(node.position.x<400)
        {
            node.physicsBody.allowsRotation=FALSE;
            ///just for fun
            node.physicsBody.linearDamping=10;
            node.physicsBody.angularVelocity=10*10;
            //where _gameHero is magnet fulling object
            [node.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake((10*10)*(_gameHero.position.x-      node.position.x),(10*10)*(_gameHero.position.y-node.position.y)) atPoint:CGPointMake(_gameHero.position.x,_gameHero.position.y)];

        }
    }
}
```

remember both hero and coin body need be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Well seems like now you can since Apple introduced [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html) in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Well you use the following code snippets to do what you're looking for, but it doesn't have `attraction` and `repulsion` properties

Body code:

```
let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "vortex")
                            node.name = "vortex"
                            node.position = position
                            node.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat.pi, duration: 1)))
                            node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: node.size.width / 2)
                            node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

                            node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.vortex.rawValue
                            node.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.player.rawValue
                            node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
                            addChild(node)
```

Upon contact with the that blackhole body:

```
func playerCollided(with node: SKNode) {
        if node.name == "vortex" {
            player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
            isGameOver = true
            score -= 1

            let move = SKAction.move(to: node.position, duration: 0.25)
            let scale = SKAction.scale(to: 0.0001, duration: 0.25)
            let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move, scale, remove])

            player.run(sequence) { [unowned self] in
                self.createPlayer()
                self.isGameOver = false
            }
        }
```